Likelihood from posterior
This question is strange and perhaps silly but it would be very useful for my research. Is there any method to find the likelihood given a prior distribution and its corresponding posterior distribution (both multinomial)?

Can you tell  us the context this arises?  Here is a relevant post:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/645776/how-to-obtain-px-given-samples-from-pyx-and-py

You could start your ideas with Bayes Theorem
